# Webpage overflowing on the right

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to make a website and have hit a bump.

The website is [here](http://commercialwaterheating.com/testing/), and as you can see, it's possible to scroll to the right, which I don't want to happen.

I think the problem is with the following element:

```
.logo_bg {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}
```

which relates (I hope) to the container that holds the logo and the text at the top of the page. I think width being 100% is the problem, but I'm not sure why; it seems to span more than 100% at the moment.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has to do with the width/placement of your logo_image div class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

`.logo_text` `width: 100%`

`.logo_image` `position: relative`

Comment: That's great thank you. The only issue is that the text is now right aligned. How do I move the logo_text to the center? Thanks!

Comment: The text should be centered.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be. I have updated the style sheet and uploaded so you can see. Thank you.

Comment: Please clear the cache. On my browser it's centered, only the image on the top a little bit too left. Could you provide a JSFiddle and make a collaboration, so that I can see the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Remove left from the logo_image class to center it and fix the overflow.

Also add left: 0; to your logo_text, because it has padding 40px from parent plus 100% width (100% + 80px [overflow]) or just remove the width and position it relative